# Updating linux kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling

Is it possible to update the Linux kernel without installing a new version of the Linux distro? If I want to download the kernel from the Linux website and manually install by compiling it, how can it be exactly done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can update linux kernel without updating your linux distro.
To install the latest kernel you can always visit http://kernel.ubuntu.com and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel to see what's going on.
As of today the latest kernel is 3.17.

If you are using ubuntu 14.04, for example goto this link: [Install/Upgrade to Linux Kernel 3.17 in Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-upgrade-kernel-3-17-ubuntu/)

Similar tutorials are for other Ubuntu version and other linux kernel version are available, just google it or comment here i'll help you.